# updating from `sass` to `scss` in angular

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

when I create my angular app, I used the params as `--style=sass` But I would switch to `scss` for that again i run `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` and changed all files ext to `.scss`.

But still getting error as :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.sass' in 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/footer/footer.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './footer.component.sass' in 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\app\footer'
ERROR in ./src/app/header/header.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './header.component.sass' in 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\app\header'
ERROR in ./src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './home.component.sass' in 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\app\pages\home'
ERROR in multi ./src/assets/css/reset.css ./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\assets\css\reset.css' in 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp'
ERROR in multi ./src/assets/css/reset.css ./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp\src\styles.sass' in 'C:\DHL\Projects\retailApp'
```

what is the issue here? any one help me

Answer (score 3):

According to error, this will changed all files extension but not imports.
So, you need to manually change all imports in all the components from `sass` to `scss` like this

```
@Component({
  ........
  styleUrls: [ './marketing.component.scss' ] // change here
   ............
})
```

Answer (score 2):

All of your files have references to SASS files.

You need to open every file stated there, and look at the decorator of the class that will look like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'XX'
  templateUrl: XXX.html
  styleUrls: ['XX.sass']
})
export class XXX {}
```

replace `sass` with `scss` and you should be good.